# Evans - What is $\Delta^2 u$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, notation, partial-derivative

Evans uses, but does not define $\Delta^2 u$. This is not $D^2 u$ which he uses for the Hessian. $Du$ is the gradient, $\Delta u$ is the laplacian, and its not $(\Delta u)^2$. So I am clueless. I couldn't find it in the index of notation.

Comment: I would guess it's the Laplacian of the Laplacian of $u$, $\Delta(\Delta u)$.

Comment: The laplacian of a laplacian?

Comment: Yes, $\Delta^2 u=\nabla ^4 u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this link to the Biharmonic equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation)

It is defined for $u:U\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ as:
$$\Delta^2 u= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \partial_i\partial_i\partial_j\partial_j u$$

Where we have used the short hand: $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}.$